# Band specific pages in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, view

I need some help coming up with a strategy to allow "band pages". Basically, I have a website for bands with products. The website is powered by Drupal, so:

- there are views that display the bands
- a band is stored as a taxonomy term
- a taxonomy term is assigned to a user using "user_terms" (so I know which username belongs to which taxonomy term)

I have a view that displays pages in this format: mysite.com/band/BANDNAME

I want these pages to be themed differently depending on the band. So, I would assume:

- I need to create a complete drupal theme per band?
- I need to assign the new themes to the various pages

So my questions:

1. Is this the best way to do it?
2. What can I use to assign the themes to the various pages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much the different band sites need to vary, you could use something like the [Context module](https://drupal.org/project/context) to create separate "contexts" for each band based on the URL and then assign different page templates depending on the context.

If you wanted to switch themes entirely, you could use the [Switchtheme module](http://drupal.org/project/switchtheme) for that.